# clojure.zip/branch? got a NullPointerException on a xml node

Tags: xml, clojure

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="library.xsd">
  <SingleBook>
  </SingleBook>
</library>
```

And my clojure (1.5.1) program crashes and get a NullPointerException while calling (zip/branch?)

```
(let [f (.toFile (sh/getPath "lib.xml"))
    dom (clojure.zip/xml-zip (clojure.xml/parse f))
    top (clojure.zip/children dom)
    ]
    (prn (first top))
    (prn (clojure.zip/branch? (first top)))
)
```

I am new to clojure.zip and clojure.xml. Can anyone tell me why it crashes? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to explain what sh/getPath is. It takes a string as path and turns it to a java.nio.file.Path.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the children, you get the a seq of the *content* of the node, not the zipper itself. You will navigate from the top node and can keep using your zipper by `clojure.zip/down` like this:

```
(clojure.zip/branch? (clojure.zip/down dom))
```

Check [clojuredocs.org about xml-zip](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.zip/xml-zip) for more info!